# R. Retaining rows from one data frame based on values in a second

Tags: r

I have two data frames. One data frame consists of four columns, the forth column contains a number which refers to a physical position.

The second data frame also has four columns. Here columns 2 and 3 refer to boundaries.

I'm trying to retain every row from data frame one when the number specified in V4 falls between the V2 and V3 specified in any row of data frame two. So if 62765 from data frame one V4 falls between  20140803-20223538, 63549983-63556677, or  52236330-52315441 in data frame two in the example the whole row should be retained, if not it is to be omitted.

I would also like to be able to perform the opposite i.e retain every row when V4 does not fall between V2 and V3 in data frame two. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

data frame one

```
V1 V2         V3  V4
10 rs11511647  0  62765
10 rs12218882  0  84172
10 rs10904045  0  84426
10 rs11252127  0  88087
```

Data frame two

```
V1  V2         V3     V4
 7 20140803 20223538   7A5
19 63549983 63556677  A1BG
10 52236330 52315441  A1CF
```

Comment: In the example you provided, none of the values in `data frame one` falls between `V2` and `V3` of `data frame two`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple appraoch:

```
# check whether values of df1$V4 are between df2$V2 and df2$V3
idx <- sapply(df1$V4, function(x) any(x >= df2$V2 & x <= df2$V3))

# remove rows
df1[idx, ]

# retain rows
df1[!idx, ]
```

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you for this it's giving me exactly what I require.

Comment: Thanks again! I have a follow up question. Could you say how this could be done by using V4 in data frame 2? What I'd want would be every row of data frame one where from V4 falls between V2 and V3 of data frame two  for the value specified in V4 of data frame two? So in the example I'd want to extract every row from V4 of data frame one  between 20140803 20223538, then extract every row of data frame one where V4 fell between 63549983 63556677. I would be extracting as many sets from data frame one as I have rows in data frame two. Thank you!

Comment: @user3000124 Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1):

**REVISED**

Using @akrun's data and getting inspiration from @Sven Hohenstein's code, here is a another approach.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
       V1 = c(10,10,10,10),
       V2 = c("rs11511647","rs12218882","rs10904045", "rs11252127"),
       V3 = c(0,0,0,0),
       V4 = c(62765, 63549985, 84426, 88087),
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(
       V1 = c(7, 19, 10),
       V2 = c(20140803, 63549983, 52236330),
       V3 = c(20223538, 63556677, 52315441),
       V4 = c("7A5", "A1BG", "A1CF"),
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
    rowwise %>%
    mutate(test = ifelse(any(V4 >= df2$V2 & V4 <= df2$V3), 1, 0)) %>%
    filter(test == 1)

#  V1         V2 V3       V4 test
#1 10 rs12218882  0 63549985    1
```

Comment: From the look of this it assumes the all the boundaries over lap. They do not there are gaps between the boundaries that need to be retained.

Comment: @user3000124 Thanks for your comment. My bad, I could not clearly read your question. I updated another approach here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility

```
idx <- sapply(seq(nrow(df1)), function(y) {
    df1$V4[y] > df2[y,2] & df1$V4[y] < df2[y,3]
})
df1[match(TRUE, idx),]
#   V1         V2 V3       V4
# 2 10 rs12218882  0 63549985
```